# Font SRC doesn't work in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, src

I am trying to use an external font which is located in the main site folder (erbosdraco_nova_nbp.ttf) but it doesn't work and shows the default html font.

```
@font-face

{
font-family: "fontFlightboard";
src: url('templates/erbosdraco_nova_nbp.ttf')
    ,url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}


#loginaccess {
    width:450px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#F3F3F3;
    float:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:"fontFlightboard";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark the correct answer which ever helped you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll have to convert your fonts into required formats like `eot`, `ttf`, `svg`, etc. You can go to this link to convert fonts from one type to another: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Finally, include this code as the first thing in your `CSS` file:

```
`@font-face {
    font-family: 'JosefinSlab';
    src: url(../JosefinSlab-SemiBold.eot);
    src: url(../JosefinSlab-SemiBold.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(../JosefinSlab-SemiBold.svg) format('svg'); 
}`
```

Make sure that the path of the font files are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest generating a Fontface kit from somewhere like Font Squirrel because it includes all the formats you'll need, then seeing if that fixes your problem.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@font-face{
font-family: fontFlightboard;
src: url('templates/erbosdraco_nova_nbp.ttf'),
     url('Sansation_Light.eot'); /* IE9 */
}
```